# Java Web service with Axis2 and Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I have followed this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/gs-axis.html and successfully created the web service. When i run the sample i only see the result printed not the whole xml structure as shown in the tutorial. 
second when i create a client that will point to the .wdsl and check the asynchronous option .. netbeans creates 6 files after that !!

HelloAxisworldHttpSoap11endpoint
HelloAxisworldHttpsSoap11endpoint
HelloAxisworldHttpSoap12endpoint
HelloAxisworldHttpsSoap12endpoint
HelloAxisworldHttpendpoint
HelloAxisworldHttpsendpoint

can i know what are these files ? and how can i consume my simple function that was created ?

many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files having Soap11 in file names are supportive to SOAP 1.1 version and Soap12 to SOAP 1.2 version. Files having Https denote that webservice can be accessed in secure mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the XML structure because you are in a web browser. Press ctrl+u or go to your browser's option "See sourcecode" in order to see the entire XML response.